# SAS cumulative count by unique ID and date

Tags: sas

I have a dataset like below

```
Customer_ID Vistited_Date
1234        7-Feb-20
4567        7-Feb-20
9870        7-Feb-20
1234        14-Feb-20
7654        14-Feb-20
3421        14-Feb-20
```

I am trying find the cumulative unique count of customers by date, assuming my output will be like below

```
Cust_count  Vistited_Date
3           7-Feb-20
2           14-Feb-20
```

**7-Feb-2020 has 3 unique customers**, whereas ***14-Feb-2020 has only 2 hence customer 1234 has visited already***.

Anyone knows how I could develop a data set in these conditions?

Sorry if my question is not clear enough, and I am available to give more details if necessary.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NOTE: @draycut's answer has the same logic but is faster, and I will explain why.

*@draycut's code uses one hash method, `add()`, using the return code as test for conditional increment.  My code uses `check()` to test for conditional increment and then `add` (which will never fail) to track.  The one method approach can be perceived as being anywhere from 15% to 40% faster in performance (depending on number of groups, size of groups and id reuse rate)*

You will need to track the `ID`s that have occurred in all prior groups, and exclude the tracked `ID`s from the current group count.

Tracking can be done with a `hash`, and conditional counting can be performed in a *DOW* loop over each group.  A DOW loop places the `SET` statement inside an explicit `DO`.

Example:

```
data have;
input ID Date: date9.; format date date11.;
datalines;
1234 7-Feb-20
4567 7-Feb-20
9870 7-Feb-20
1234 14-Feb-20
7654 14-Feb-20
3421 14-Feb-20
;

data counts(keep=date count);
  if _n_ =  1 then do;
    declare hash tracker();
    tracker.defineKey('id');
    tracker.defineDone();
  end;  

  do until (last.date);
    set have;
    by date;

    if tracker.check() ne 0 then do;
      count = sum(count, 1);
      tracker.add();
    end;
  end;
run;
```

Raw performance benchmark - no disk io, cpu required to fill array before doing hashing, so those performance components are combined.

The root performance is how fast can new items be added to the hash.

Simulate 3,000,000 'records', 1,000 `groups` of 3,000 `dates`, 10% id reuse (so the distinct ids will be ~2.7M).

```
%macro array_fill (top=3000000, n_group = 1000, overlap_factor=0.10);
  %local group_size n_overlap index P Q;

  %let group_size = %eval (&top / &n_group);

  %if (&group_size < 1) %then %let group_size = 1;

  %let n_overlap = %sysevalf (&group_size * &overlap_factor, floor);

  %if &n_overlap < 0 %then %let n_overlap = 0;

  %let top = %sysevalf (&group_size * &n_group);

  P = 1;
  Q = &group_size; 

  array ids(&top) _temporary_;

  _n_ = 0;
  do i = 1 to &n_group;
    do j = P to Q;
      _n_+1;
      ids(_n_) = j;
    end;
    P = Q - &n_overlap;
    Q = P + &group_size - 1;
  end;
%mend;

options nomprint;

data _null_ (label='check then add');
  length id 8;

  declare hash h();
  h.defineKey('id');
  h.defineDone();

  %array_fill;

  do index = 1 to dim(ids);
    id = ids(index);

    if h.check() ne 0 then do;
      count = sum(count,1);
      h.add();
    end;
  end;

  _n_ = h.num_items;
  put 'num_items=' _n_ comma12.;
  put index= comma12.;

  stop;
run;


data _null_ (label='just add');
  length id 8;                     

  declare hash h();
  h.defineKey('id');
  h.defineDone();

  %array_fill;

  do index = 1 to dim(ids);
    id = ids(index);

    if h.add() = 0 then
      count = sum(count,1);
  end;

  _n_ = h.num_items;
  put 'num_items=' _n_ comma12.;
  put index= comma12.;

  stop;
run;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
data have;
input Customer_ID Vistited_Date :anydtdte12.;
format Vistited_Date date9.;
datalines;
1234 7-Feb-2020
4567 7-Feb-2020
9870 7-Feb-2020
1234 14-Feb-2020
7654 14-Feb-2020
3421 14-Feb-2020
;

data want (drop=Customer_ID);
    if _N_=1 then do;
        declare hash h ();
        h.definekey ('Customer_ID');
        h.definedone ();
    end;

    do until (last.Vistited_Date);
        set have;
        by Vistited_Date;
        if h.add() = 0 then Count = sum(Count, 1);
    end;
run;
```

Answer (score 2):

If your data is not sorted and you like the SQL maybe this solution is same good for you and it is very simple:

```
    /* your example  3 rows */
    data have;
    input ID Date: date9.; format date date11.;
    datalines;
    1234 7-Feb-20
    4567 7-Feb-20
    9870 7-Feb-20
    1234 14-Feb-20
    7654 14-Feb-20
    3421 14-Feb-20
    1234 15-Feb-20
    7654 15-Feb-20
    1111 15-Feb-20
    ;
    run;

    /* simple set theory. Final dataset contains your final data like results 
    below*/

    proc sql;
    create table temp(where =(mindate=date)) as select
     ID, date,min(date) as mindate from have
        group by id;
    create table final as select count(*) as customer_count,date from temp
        group by date;
    quit;

    /* results:
    customer_count  Date
    3               07.febr.20
    2               14.febr.20
    1               15.febr.20
    */
```

Answer (score 1):

Another method cause I dont know hash so well. >_<

```
data have;
input ID Date: date9.; format date date11.;
datalines;
1234 7-Feb-20
4567 7-Feb-20
9870 7-Feb-20
1234 14-Feb-20
7654 14-Feb-20
3421 14-Feb-20
;

data want;
    length Used $200.;
    retain Used;
    set have;
    by Date;

    if first.Date then count = .;
    if not find(Used,cats(ID)) then do;
        count + 1;
        Used = catx(',',Used,ID);
    end;
    if last.Date;
    put Date= count=;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not overly concerned with processing speed and want something simple:

```
proc sort data=have;
   by id date;
** Get date of each customer's first unique visit **;
proc sort data=have out=first_visit nodupkey;
   by id;

proc freq data=first_visit noprint;
   tables date /out=want (keep=date count);
run;
```